# Looking for an example EMGU super resolution

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, emgucv

I'm trying to perform super-resolution in EMGU.
I have a microscope USB camera where I can acquire sequential frames to files (or memory).
I'm pretty new to C# but have reasonable working knowledge. I **do** have Emgu working well in VS .Net where I'm acquiring and saving images.

I want to perform super-resolution but can't find any decent example code or just examples. There's one example [**here**](https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/blob/master/Emgu.CV.Superres/SuperResolution.cs), but I'm using VS .Net and I'm having a hard time understanding.

Please any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Im sorry, i mean C#.NET